# Accessing Sharepoint Web Services without authentication

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

Is it possible to access a sharepoint web service without authenication? If you can't do it directley can you think of any ways to get round it such as haveing an open service inbetween that does authenicate for you using a public account.

Comment: I want display some content from sharepoint on another internal site where you don't log in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

John,

The security model of the web application through which you're trying to access the web service in question is going to drive whether or not you can access the service anonymously.  If you're attempting to access the web service through a web application on which anonymous access is enabled, then you'll be able to hit the web service.  Go ahead and try this on an anonymous site (if you have one): http://yoursitehere/_vti_bin/lists.asmx.  You'll get the friendly service page back, no auth required.

Here's the catch: once you traverse the web service layer, you've got another layer of security to deal with.  SharePoint itself is going to want to check permissions for access via the web services just as it normally would, so unless you are attempting an operation or trying to access data that is allowed for anonymous users, you're going to get blocked.

You have a handful of options:

1. Simply ensure that everything you're trying to do is permitted anonymously.  This may sound easy, but it can actually be pretty difficult for anything but the simplest and straightforward of operations.  Most organizations, too, don't care for opening things up to this extent.
2. If you control the code that's calling the web service, then you have the ability to attach credentials to the web service request.  I recommend starting here, as it is going to make things a *lot* easier than trying to throw everything wide open.  Plenty of examples exist on attaching credentials to a web service proxy (e.g., http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc178918.aspx)
3. Finally, you could write your own web service that wraps the SharePoint web service (or services) of interest.  You could permit anonymous access to your web service and then adopt an appropriate security context within your own service to access SharePoint with the required permissions level.

I hope this helps!

- Sean

Comment: Sean - I too thought that if BOTH IIS and SharePoint was setup for anon access then you would be able to access web services anonymously. Turns out you can't - give it a go!

Comment: Your comment got me thinking, Ryan, and so I did some additional research and playing around.  Despite all my digging, I couldn't come up with an example of accessing SharePoint data through a web service anonymously.  Though the web service endpoints are available, it doesn't look like it's possible to drill through.  Thanks for catching this, and my apologies to anyone I may have mislead.  Of the options I cite above, #2 and #3 look to be the only "real" options.  As a small follow-up: this MS article covers what's open anonymously: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191479.aspx

Comment: I've spent 4 days straight trying to determine why I'm unable to call the web services on an FBA site after being authenticated. This explains it. I am authenticated but my SharePoint CurrentUser is still null/anonymous and it is therefore denying me access with a 403 when SharePoint checks authorization on the List I'm trying to access. I'm calling the web service from a client side app so I need to use option 3. Would it be better to call the SP web service from my web service, or to just use the SP API within my web service?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can, most actions the webservices perform need an explicit user with the correct permissions set. If both sites are internal, your options might include

- Using automatic NTLM authentication, give the complete Authenticated Users group the necessary acecss. Using IE or the proper extensions to FireFox credentials will be automatically passed without user prompting. Your mileage may vary.
- Passing the proper credentials to a default user explicitly in the call to the webservice 
  from that other website.
- If you feel creative, [here](http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/?p=508) is a blog from Reza Alirezaei where he walks through the steps of mapping the anonymous user onto a specific account. If you manage to give that acount the proper permissions, you are there. Not for the faint of heart, though.